# Firebase database find key

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving some of my database data into firebase real-time database but I have issue to get/update my stored data.

## Code

This is how I save my data in firebase

```
//...
$user->save();
//then
$factory = new Factory;
$firebase = $factory
->withServiceAccount(base_path(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')))
->withDatabaseUri('https://myapp-d54e6.firebaseio.com/');
$database = $firebase->createDatabase();

$newUser = $database
->getReference('user')
->push($user);
```

Now what I get in firebase is like:

[image: one]

As you see firebase store my data under its own `uid` which makes it hard for me to find and update my data (which made me ask this question).

## Issue

Now in my update function when I want to find my user and update its data I have to find firebase uid then get those data.

in update function I have:

```
$user->save();
// now that my DB is updated, start to update firebase
$factory = new Factory;
$firebase = $factory
->withServiceAccount(base_path(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')))
->withDatabaseUri('https://myapp-d54e6.firebaseio.com/');
$database = $firebase->createDatabase();

$getData = $database->getReference('users')->getvalue();

$userIDs = [];
foreach($getData as $userData) {
  $userIDs [] = $userData['id'];
}

if(in_array($id, $userIDs )){
  return $id;
} else {
  return 'no';
}

// update part remained for after complete fetching my data..!
```

This `return $id` return user id and not firebase uid (at this point all I gained was being sure that such data exist in firebase :/ ) + I still don't have full data of this user as I only made array of ids in foreach above.

## Question

**How can I get my user data from firebase and update them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

Thanks to `Frank van Puffelen` answer it was great lead to me, here is how I solved this issue.

```
$user->save();
// now that my DB is updated, start to update firebase
$factory = new Factory;
$firebase = $factory
->withServiceAccount(base_path(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')))
->withDatabaseUri('https://myapp-d54e6.firebaseio.com/');
$database = $firebase->createDatabase();

$getData = $database->getReference('users')->getvalue();


foreach($getData as $key_user => $userr) {
    // In case of using variables outside of this loop
    //if(in_array($id, $userr)) {
        //$final_user = $userr;
        //$fireKey = $key_user;
    //}
    $newUser = $database
    ->getReference('users')
    ->getChild($key_user)
    ->set($user);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to change this code:

```
$newUser = $database
->getReference('user')
->push($user);
```

When you call `push()`, Firebase creates a unique ID for the new data. What you want instead is to store the new data under a key you control, the UID of the user. That'd look something like this:

```
$newUser = $database
->getReference('user')
->getChild("the uid of the user")
->set($user);
```

For `getChild("the uid of the user")` you'll then have to use the UID of the user, which unfortunately I can't see where to get it from in your code.

Comment: thank you that helped a lot, will let you know if i could fix it

Comment: Thank you its fixed.